# Where is the default ruby installed directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I try to delete all ruby related folders and gems. Do you know hoe to find all these and where is the ruby directory in ubuntu?

Comment: It depends on how it was installed. You could post your question on [AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/q/95) community. Link will follow you to the answer.

Comment: If you use rvm, you don't have to worry about deleting the default installation, and your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all gems, follow this page:

http://geekystuff.net/2009/01/14/remove-all-ruby-gems/

Works like a charm