# Which location, on Ubuntu, is Ruby 1.9 installed to when using the package manager?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500089/where-is-the-default-ruby-installed-directory-in-ubuntu), but the only answer doesn't really answer the question.

When I use apt-get to install Ruby 1.9, which location on the hard-drive does Ruby get installed to?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really know the answer, but couldn't you just do `find / -name "*ruby*"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
dpkg -L ruby
```

it should print out the files belonging to package ruby.